# Python client server

Tags: python, ip, client, telnet

i've been trying to learn how to work with Telnet in python and I just got stuck on something.
importent to mention- I have no clue about anything in this subject. IP, telnet, sockets.. Nothing at all..
let's say this is my server:

```
import socket
import sys
HOST = ''
PORT = 8886 
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created'
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error , msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()
print 'Socket bind complete'     
s.listen(10)
print 'Socket now listening'
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])
print 'sending msg'
conn.sendall('My name is: ')
print 'msg sent'
data = conn.recv(1024)
print data
x="Hello %s and Thank you for your help! :)"%data
conn.sendall(x)
conn.close()
s.close()
```

Now this is just a basic thing for testing..
I was trying to create a client that wil connect to the server from a place far away, so I couldn't use localhost.
this is what i managed to do:

```
import socket
import sys
import time 
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('85.65.110.8',8886))
data= sock.recv(1024)
lol=raw_input(data)
sock.sendall(lol)
data = sock.recv(1024)
print data
time.sleep(3)
sock.close()
```

the IP 85.65.110.8 is what i found from whatismyip.com- and it doesn't work even from my own computer.
I tried the IP 192.168.0.100 which works from the LAN but not from my friends house (who is testing it) and 'localhost' works aswell (still from me but not from my friend's house)
how can i change this so my friend could connect to the server?
thanks :)
(my Firewall is down and I port-forwarded.. I think... I hope so...)

Comment: You should have program `telnet` (`telnet.exe`) on your system so you can use it to test your server - using terminal/cmd.exe and command `telnet localhost 8886` (or your friend `telnet 85.65.110.8 8886`). BTW: Your Internet Provider can have own firewall and it can change your IP every day.

Comment: I tried with CMD but still the server doesn't seem to respond when i try to connect to it..

Answer (score 1):

If it works with the internal IP (192.168.x.x), but not with the external one (from whatsmyip, but remember it can change at any time without warning), then it is almost certainly a firewall or port-forwarding problem.

Unfortunately there's not enough information in your post to troubleshoot it (and firewalls go on SuperUser rather than StackOverflow in any case).

Comment: the thing is that with the external IP I can't even connect with my own computer..
umm I just noticed that instead of port forwarding i did something called a "virtual Server" or something... is that the same?...

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some router to connect to internet
so `85.65.110.8` is external address of this router.

On router you have to use `port forwarding` or `virtual server`
and set connection `router 8886 <=> 192.168.0.100 8886`

When someone will try to connect to `85.65.110.8 8886` then router will send this to `192.168.0.100 8886` and will send back all answers from `192.168.0.100 8886`

If Internet Provider blocks some ports (for example `8886`) then use `80`.
It is web server port. (`router 80 <=> 192.168.0.100 8886`).
Then your friend will have to connect to `85.65.110.8 80` but your server will run on port `8886`.

If Internet Provider changes your IP every day then you will need http://no-ip.com or http://dyndns.com .

Your friend can use `telnet` to test your port - or something more specialized like [nmap](http://nmap.org/) or [other port scanning tools](http://sectools.org/tag/port-scanners/)

Comment: Not sure I really managed to follow.. this is the Port Forwarding screen I got : http://puu.sh/9WIJ6/75a1246075.png
what is "router 80"? according to the port forwarding screen can you tell me what to write in each place? thank you!

Comment: `router 80` means `IP:actual_external_ip PORT:80`(at that moment it means `85.65.110.8 80`) - I have advanced configuration in router. I saw image - `telnet1` is OK , `telnet2` is useless. Now with `telnet1` you have forwarding `85.65.110.8 8880 <=> 192.168.0.100 8880` so you have to change both ports in `telnet1` to `8886` or use port `8880` in your server. Now you can run server (with port `8880`) and friend can try to connect to `85.65.110.8 8880`

Comment: so i changed the server port to 8880 and it still doesn't work.. I don't know why.. when I run the client it's like it's not even connecting.. as you can see the server will print as soon as a client is connected to it, and it just doesn't do anything.. it's not even ending the program it's just running and doing nothing..
is there any information I could give so that you would understand the problem better?

Comment: Run server again (with port `8880`) and try `telnet localhost 8880`. Does it work ? Then check whether you still have external IP `85.65.110.8`. Then run server again and try `telnet 85.65.110.8 8880`. Does it work ?

Comment: ran with port 8880.. localhost worked perfectly (i was doing a step by step of the client script to see if anything goes wrong)
checked and my external IP is still 85.65.110.8
ran again, tried a step by step using 85.65.110.8. it didn't throw any error when I was trying to connect, but when I reached the data=sock.recv(1024) it started running and doing nothing.. just a blank.. after a while it finished and data had nothing in it..
http://puu.sh/9WQqH/0571ab8cbb.png

Comment: by the way does this have anything to do with it?
http://puu.sh/9WRcy/32e409ac7f.png

Comment: You could set `endpoint indenpendent`, or `enable DMZ` with `192.168.0.100` or both. Did you try to use `telnet 85.65.110.8 8880` in place of your client script ?

Comment: BTW: You can try to use script to connect to me `79.184.89.116 8880`. Server is running.

Comment: I got message `Daniel` :)

Comment: so it worked with you.. I did all those things and it still does the same.. I tried to connect using cmd and it just kept loading and doing nothing at all..

Comment: do you have enough reputation to chat? I think it might be easier this way

Comment: I thing you are blocked by your Internet Provider and you can't do anything. I have no more ideas. I could only use external computer with access to its system and python (some VPS with Linux) - maybe free account on [PythonAnywhere.com](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) or free account on [OpehShift.com](https://www.openshift.com/)

Comment: I see.. and Incase i am blocked by my internet provider, there's nothing I can do? at all? is there anyway to check if i am blocked or it will remain as a guess only?